# Getting Started with CEF for the windows api

Tags: c++, chromium-embedded

I'm trying to get started using chromium embedded using the windows api. I have managed to open and run the example project, but I have no clue of where to go from there. The CEF wiki has no examples of use on windows, and while I have found tutorials for gtk+ ( https://github.com/aphistic/cef3barebones ), it isn't going to help me much with integration in the windows api. I am in the process of studying the example application, but it is very complicated compared for the basic functionality I a looking for  Anybody have any adivice on what to do to try an learn CEF on windows? Is there any tutorials on windows that I haven't found yet?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CEF's main sample application, **cefclient**, works on Windows, Linux and MacOS X.  It is implemented with the Win32 API.

The main difference between the platforms is their native UI frameworks.  You must inspect the test project more precisely.

Review the following to learn more about CEF:

1. Read the CEF wiki.
2. Review the cef3barebones blog post http://blog.erikd.org/2013/01/14/chromium-embedded-framework-3-bare-bones/ (it still good to know, even for non-gtk frameworks).
3. Read CEF header files - each function is documented.

Comment: Correct, there is no other way then using cefclient.

Comment: CEF API bounded to Windows only in handle types. It is definitely needed examples about passing handles in API? While nowadays ceflient and cefsimple exists, and this is more than enough.